# LibreOffice problem while openning a document

Tags: libreoffice

My problem is that when I try to open one specific .odt document, I can't move the page or do anything except moving the mouse, which is useless. Also, the mouse, when I'm on the document, is freaking out switching between mouse and loader couple of times per second. It also becomes dark when I click on the document like if it's not responding.

Comment: Are the other apps running smooth or do you have any other issues regarding running a different app? I ask this because it looks like some kind of high resource consumption.

Comment: All smooth and fast

Comment: I'd uninstall LibreOffice completely using Synaptic and then install it again from scratch.

Comment: But the problem is only with one file, if I open another one, everything's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upload your .odt document to Google Drive.
2. Right-click on the .odt document and select *Open with* -> *Google Docs*. Google Docs will convert the .odt file to its own document format for editing in Google Docs.
3. From the open document in Google Docs select *File* -> *Download as* -> *OpenDocument Format (.odt)*. Google Docs will convert the document back to .odt format.
4. Open the .odt document that you downloaded from Google Docs in LibreOffice.

Google Docs does a good job of converting documents to .odt format. The two document conversions in Google Docs may remove whatever there is in your original .odt document that was causing the problem.

---

**Alternate method**

1. Make a copy of the corrupted document and rename the copied document's extension to .zip.
2. Open the .zip file in Archive Manager and extract the content.xml file and the images from the Pictures folder.
3. Open the content.xml file in a text editor and recover as much of the text as you can. The content.xml file may also contain some of the original document's formatting information, which can also be recovered. If the content.xml contains any formatting information, the best way to view it is by opening content.xml in a web browser.
4. Sometimes you can also recover a corrupted .odt document by creating a blank .odt document, renaming its extension to .zip, and replacing the content.xml file of the blank .odt document with the content.xml file which was extracted from the corrupted document.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my case, all the tables are messed up, theres only 5 pages when it is supposed to have 16, but to recover the text, it's a very good method. thank you!

Comment: Please provide a link to your .odt document, so that I can try to open the document in Google Tables in order to see if I can recover your messed up tables that way. Make sure that you delete any private data out of the document before you provide a link for it!

Comment: I can't modify the document, so I'm not able to remove the private data. If I send you the google doc, it's all messed up and you won't be able to make it back like I want. Thanks for the help though, I'll do it again

Comment: Maybe you can fix the doc yourself. Right click on the doc in Google Drive. Select _Open with_ -> _Connect more apps_. This will open a mini Google Drive app store pane. Connect Google Tables to Google Drive. Then open your doc in Google Tables, and see if Google Tables can do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider attempting recovery, rebooting and giving Libre Office one more chance. In one case I received harsh messages such as

> General error. General input/output error

or after a few rounds of failed auto-recovery attempts

> The file 'filename.ods' is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened. LibreOffice can try to repair the file. The corruption could be the result of document manipulation or of structural document damage due to data transmission. We recommend that you do not trust the content of the repaired document. Execution of macros is disabled for this document. Should LibreOffice repair the file?

which failed too.

However, after rebooting, I found that that the corrupted document was only being regarded as *locked for editing by another user*. I could then make a copy of it and start off from scratch. This may well be circumstantial but consider giving LO one more chance.

My situation: LibreOffice 4.2.8.2; Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; Linux kernel 3.13.0-101-generic