# General input/output error while accessing odt document

Tags: libreoffice

I set the immutable attribute on an .odt document.

When I try to open it with LibreOffice, it says "General input/output error while accessing."

I don't get that message when opening a text file with the immutable attribute.

Is there a way to stop that error?

Comment: See if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491292/general-error-general-input-output-error-when-opening-documents-with-libreoff) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368051/libreoffice-problem-while-openning-a-document) help.

Comment: None of the items on those pages helped.

Answer (score 0):

I see this error in **LibreOffice v. 6.0.1.1** when I try to open a file from read-only media (CD/DVD-ROM) or from a mounted ISO image. (Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 17.10).

I'd say it was reported in this bug: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113024

Answer (score 0):

I believe that trying to open a file with the immutable attribute fails because LibreOffice expects to be able to change meta data. I found that setting the read-only attribute accomplished my goal.